# How does the logic behind shuffling an array work?

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I am having issues understanding the logic behind how the array is shuffled. If someone could explain step by step that would be extremely helpful.

```
//Shuffle the cards
for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
  //Generate an index randomly 
  int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
  System.out.println(index);
  int temp = deck[i];
  deck[i] = deck[index];
  deck[index] = temp;           
}
```

Comment: It generates a random number with an upper bound of array length and swaps the current element with the element at that index. `int index = randomInstance.nextInt(deck.length)` would be better to use though.

Comment: It's a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @avi I don't believe this is a Fisher-Yates shuffle as previous cards may end up in their earlier position, which is not the case for Fisher-Yates.

Comment: @WJS Ah, you're right; good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let go through it, step by step

```
for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
```

For loop, will iterates through your deck. Code below will be called dependent on the size of deck.

```
  //Generate an index randomly 
  int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
```

How the comment already says, it generates a random number and multiply it with deck lengths. Will be saved on the variable called index and will be a Integer.

```
  System.out.println(index);
```

This just outprints your random number.

```
  int temp = deck[i];
```

Is a temporary variable. It saves the value from your array at the position i.

```
  deck[i] = deck[index];
```

Sets the value at position i in deck to the value that is in deck at position index.

```
  deck[index] = temp;
```

The temp will be stored at the pos index in deck.

Hope the step by step helped you

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful and I know understand where I was getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

The loop iterates through the deck one card at a time, and swaps that card with a randomly selected card in the deck. After the loop each card will have been swapped at least once.

Comment: Its not guaranteed that each card as been swapped at least once. Highly unlikely but still probable.

Comment: @locus2k Yes, a card could be swapped with itself, or swapped and swapped back again later, but those details aren't really that important for understanding how the algorithm works.

Comment: @locus2k  I was curious so I just did a test. In 1M iterations of the shuffle, a card ended up in the same place just over half the time.  So I would say that is pretty likely.

Answer (score 0):

It simply swaps a card at the current index with the card at the randomly generated index.  The generated index will be between `0` and `deck.length-1` inclusive.

It is not a perfect shuffle though as the index `i` could equal the randomly generated index.  Or they could later reverse a previously swapped card.

For more information on `shuffling` you may also want to check out this article on [Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).